# NullPointerException error while implementing Hash Table in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am implementing Hash Table through java. When I implement the following code, I get a NullPointer Exception error but if I replace the else statement in void put(int key, int value) in class HashTable with the statement kv[key]=new KeyValue(key,value); It works! Can someone explain why is this happening? Please help!

```
public class KeyValue {
    int key;
    int value;

    KeyValue(int k, int v)
    {
        key = k; 
        value = v;
    }
    public int getKey(){
        return key;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void put(int k, int v)
    {
        key = k;
        value = v;
    }

}

public class HashTable{

    KeyValue[] kv;

        HashTable(){
            kv = new KeyValue[4];
            for (int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
            {    kv[i]=null;

            }
        }

    void put(int key, int value)
        {
            if((kv[key]!=null) || (key<0 && key>=4))
            {
                ;
            }
            else
            {
                kv[key].put(key,value);
            }
        }

        int get(int key)
        {
            int value;

            value=kv[key].getValue();


            return value;
        }

    public static void main(String[] a){

            HashTable h = new HashTable();
            h.put(1,2);

            System.out.println(h.get(1));

        }

}
```

Comment: My comment became too long, so I posted it as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23080964/3239833).

Comment: This is not a hash table. It is basically an array-wrapper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are initializing `kv[key]` with null. So if you do `kv[key].callSomeMethod` you got an `NullPointerException` because there is no object to call a method of.

You can initialize your `KeyValues` like Peter Radar said or do it in the constructor of your `HashTable` using the default constructor of `KeyValue`.

```
    HashTable(){
        kv = new KeyValue[4];
        for (int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
        {    
            kv[i]=new KeyValue();
        }
    }
```

Now an Object of type `KeyValue` is stored in `kv[i]` and you can use its methods.

Comment: In other words: new KeyValue[4] initializes the array, but it just creates it filled with nulls, any single object must be initialized

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question I believe kai and Peter Rader found the issue. But there are other things in your code that I recommend to change.

The `KeyValue.put` method should be renamed to `set` or completely dropped. The basic question is here if `KeyValue` should be a mutable data object or not.

In `HashTable.put` the your code `if((kv[key]!=null) || (key<0 && key>=4))` should read `if ((kv[key]!=null) || key<0 || key>=4)` (besides you should of course replace `4` with a variable so you can have larger HashTables too).

Since you are trying to learn something from this I'd also recommend that you try to replace `KeyValue[] kv;` with a [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to implement something very basic so that's why I used 4. Thanks for the advice though. Also ((kv[key]!=null) || key<0 || key>=4) doesn't solve my purpose as I am checking that whether the user enters a key within this range (key<0 && key>=4) or not. Because all the keys are defined in this range so it doesn't work for a key entered by the user that doesn't exist. BTW who is Peter Radar? I can't see his comment/answer, I can only see kai's answer!!!

Comment: @Meha: But `key<0 && key>=4` can never be true! `key` can not at the same time be smaller than 0 and larger than 4 :) Its `key<0 || key>=4` you are looking for. The answer by Peter seems to be retired.

Comment: Its this (key>0 && key<=4) what I was wanting to do :D ... there was a typo. And what you said can also be done.. its the same thing. Thanks!